# memory disordered in simple c strtok_r test

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

I have the following simple c program :

```
struct MarketOrderBook
{
    double price ;
    int    volume ;
};

struct DataFeed
{
    char symbol[16] ; //tag 48
    char exchange[16] ;  //tag 207
    char yymm[8] ;  //tag 200
    int  totalvolumetraded ;  //tag 387
    double tradeprice ;
    int  tradevolume ;
    MarketOrderBook BidOrder[5] ;
    MarketOrderBook AskOrder[5] ;
} ;

#define DATAFEEDCNT 256
int dostrtok(char* buf,char* ptr[])
{
    int in=0 ;
    char *token ;
    char *rest = buf ;
    //char pipe[2]={0x01,0x00} ;
    char pipe[2]={'|',0x00} ;
    while((token=strtok_r(rest,pipe,&rest))!=NULL) {
        ptr[in] = token ;
        in++ ;
        if( in > DATAFEEDCNT )
            break ;
    } //while
    return in ;
} //dostrtok

#define PRICECLIENT_VALUE_SIZE 128

void DoGetTagAndValue( char *ptr,char* leftvar,char* rightval )
{
    int idx=-1,ileftidx=0,irightidx=0;
    int leftpartend=0 ;
    while( 1 ){
        idx++ ;
        if( ptr[idx] == 0x00 || ptr[idx] == 0x01 || ptr[idx] == '|' )
            break ;
        if( ptr[idx] == '=' ){
            leftpartend=1 ;
            continue;
        }
        if( leftpartend == 0 ){
            leftvar[ileftidx++] = ptr[idx] ;
        }
        if( leftpartend == 1 ){
            if( irightidx >= PRICECLIENT_VALUE_SIZE )
                break ;
            rightval[irightidx++] = ptr[idx] ;
        }
    } //while
}//DoGetTagAndValue

void DoDealIncomeData( int inum,char**ptr )
{
    char ArrLeftVar[258][8]={0} ;
    char ArrRightVal[258][PRICECLIENT_VALUE_SIZE]={0} ;

    for(int idx=0;idx<inum;idx++){
        char leftvar[8]={0} ;
        char rightval[PRICECLIENT_VALUE_SIZE]={0} ;
        DoGetTagAndValue( ptr[idx],leftvar,rightval ) ;
        printf("(%s)=(%s) ",leftvar,rightval);
        if( idx < 258 ){
            strcpy( ArrLeftVar[idx] , leftvar ) ;
            strcpy( ArrRightVal[idx] , rightval ) ;
        }
    } //for
    printf("\n");

    DataFeed datafeed ;
    printf("*******(%s)************\n",datafeed.symbol);

    return ;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char xyz[128]={0} ;

    sprintf(xyz,"%s","8=FIX.4.2|9=00073|35=A|49=ABCD|56=XYZ|34=1|52=20160318-07:40:32.956|108=30|98=0|10=197|");

    printf("xyz=(%s)\n",xyz);
    char* ptr[DATAFEEDCNT]={0} ;
    int inum = dostrtok(xyz,ptr) ;
    printf("inum=(%d)\n",inum);
    DoDealIncomeData(inum,ptr) ;

    while(1)
    {
        sleep( 5 ) ;
    } //while
} //main
```

Then I compile it by : g++ --std=c++11 testx.cpp -o testx.exe
in g++ 4.8.3  and result :

```
xyz=(8=FIX.4.2|9=00073|35=A|49=ABCD|56=XYZ|34=1|52=20160318-07:40:32.956|108=30|98=0|10=197|)

inum=(10)

(8)=(FIX.4.2) (9)=(00073) (35)=(A) (49)=(ABCD) (56)=(XYZ) (34)=(1) (52)=(20160318-07:40:32.956) (108)=(30) (98)=(0) (10)=(197) 

*******(197)************
```

I think datafeed.symbol should display NULL string , but what surprise me 
is that it display 197 , it showed that memory has disordered in this test,
before I  use another solution of this test , I am still curious 
what part I do wrong to make this happened ?!

Comment: Are you talking about this line `printf("*******(%s)************\n",datafeed.symbol);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the comments your question is about what happens in the line `printf("*******(%s)************\n",datafeed.symbol);`

As we can see that the `datafeed` object is just created in the line above we can shorten down your entire code to this example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MarketOrderBook
{
    double price;
    int    volume;
};

struct DataFeed
{
    char symbol[16]; //tag 48
    char exchange[16];  //tag 207
    char yymm[8];  //tag 200
    int  totalvolumetraded;  //tag 387
    double tradeprice;
    int  tradevolume;
    MarketOrderBook BidOrder[5];
    MarketOrderBook AskOrder[5];
};


int main()
{
    DataFeed datafeed;
    printf("*******(%s)************\n", datafeed.symbol);
}
```

We can than reduce this example to something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct DataFeed
{
    char symbol[16]; //tag 48
};


int main()
{
    DataFeed datafeed;
    printf("*******(%s)************\n", datafeed.symbol);
}
```

And even further to this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char symbol[16];
    printf("*******(%s)************\n", datafeed.symbol);
}
```

So when you look at this code you can clearly see that you are invoking undefined behaviour as symbol isn't initialized.

That your program prints `"107"` is just because that's some data lying around in the memory of your `symbol` array.